# Is using a 12.5V PSU ok for a 12V LED? Also would this wiring work?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, led-strip

I am looking to make a small central box to control my LED strips from. However, the switches I've bought are 12V, I only have a 12.5V plug power supply and the LED strips are 5V.

I was told a 1000Ω resistor would take 12V down to 5V. (I'm not accounting for any current difference or wattage, I'm new to electronics.)

Would this work? What issues might I run into?

This is the switches schematic:

https://www.seebay.co.uk/media/catalog/product/h/a/halo-wiring_3.jpg

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Ez3H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Thanks for all the advice and the explanation. However for my instance it was me being stupid, I thought the switch LED required 12V as it only lit up when I tried it with 12V and not when I tryed it with 5V. This was because I wasn't linking the - and C to allow it to light up when powered. Sorry

Comment: Do you have LED datasheet? How much current is expected per strip?

Comment: If you link the strips, people can tell you how to make this work. But no, that won't work.

Comment: Q1 How many mA do the strips draw? | Using a resistor dropper is unwise but doable. R = delta-V/I_LED = (12-5)/I_LED . So for 100 mA = 0.1 A R= v_/I = (12-7)/0.1 = 50 Ohms. Change current to suit.

Comment: The question in title contradicts the slim body of text. Far more specs are needed

Comment: To answer the title, most of the time, 12.5V regulated power supply will be fine for a led designed for 12V. It will be a little brighter and not last as long, but the voltage change is minimal. This is because it's likely a regular led with a resistor calculated for 12V.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

No, this will not work.  Right now your strip's + is connected to ground, the most that would happen is that the strips power connections would both be grounded.  But even worse is the simple fact that your switches have NO ground connection, so turning them on would have no effect.

I edit this shortly with a diagram showing how to fix it, DONE.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft8Q67.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With a 250 resistor your going to get about 28 mA. The way to calculate is below.
Finding the value of the resistor is easy once you know what the strips current requirements are.

Here I'm going to use 30mA as the required current.
First determine how much voltage that the resistor will need to drop.
12V(source) - 5V(required) = 7V
Now we solve for resistance(ohms) by dividing the voltage(in volts) by the current(in amps): R = V/I = 12/.03 = 233 Ohms.
The resistor will have to handle watts = V x I = 7 x .03 = .21 watts, I would bump that to half a watt.  This will require either a single 1210 240 ohm, or 5 0605/0805 47 ohm resistors in series to handle the 1/2 watt that will be dissipated in the resistor.

Comment: This answer is dangerous as the OP does not know enough to specify the correct resistor value AND you have not explained how to apply what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  I hope it's better now.  I semi-explain the method.

Comment: Better :-)     .............

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make 5V at very low current (uA) from 12V with 1k but not supply LEDstrips probably xA@ 5V so more like 1~10Ohm load. So this is not possible.

You need a 5V supply that exceeds your load current.  RGB LEDstrips have Serial data controlled logic controlled PWM  rightness control.  The only proper solution is a 5V supply.  Even the controller should not require 12V for controlled switches.

Comment: Better yet, find out what current it needs and give it a constant source per string.  I  think the OP already has the power supplies, so without the datasheet I would guess 25 - 30ma and replace the 1K with a 250.

Comment: @GB-AE7OO they mention led controller, so it's not a constant current source needed.

Comment: He is building a controller box.  Right now he has a 12V power source and switches that he is combining from the looks of it.

Comment: RGB strings need a 5V voltage source and never a current source.

Comment: This is all based on the flimsy evidence that it is a 5V stripled.of the 5m type.